# Entity Framework query to generate SQL expected

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, optimization

I have two Tables `A` and `B`. `A` is related to `B` as one-to-many (`A` contains collection of `B`).

How can I make Entity Framework to generate next SQL (what linq query should i write):

```
SELECT A.UserId, COUNT(B.ID) FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON A.ID = B.A_ID
WHERE B.Score <= 6
GROUP BY A.UserId
```

I have tried next:

```
from a in db.A
join b in db.B 
on a.ID equals b.A_ID
where b.Score <= 6
group a by a.UserId into grouping
select new 
{
    UserId = (Guid) grouping.Key,                       
    RawValue = grouping.Sum(x => x.Bs.Count())
};
```

It returns me what I need but EF translates it into horrible query (that's why performance of this query is very bad).

Generated SQL:

```
SELECT 
1 AS [C1], 
[Project3].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
 CAST( [Project3].[C1] AS float) AS [C3]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Project2].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
(SELECT 
    SUM([Filter2].[A1]) AS [A1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        (SELECT 
            COUNT(1) AS [A1]
            FROM [dbo].[B] AS [Extent5]
            WHERE [Extent3].[ID] = [Extent5].[A_ID]) AS [A1]
        FROM  [dbo].[A] AS [Extent3]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[B] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent3].[ID] = [Extent4].[A_ID]
        WHERE ([Extent4].[Score] <= 6) 
    )  AS [Filter2]) AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Distinct1].[UserId] AS [UserId]
    FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT 
        [Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId]
        FROM  [dbo].[A] AS [Extent1]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[B] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ID] = [Extent2].[A_ID]
        WHERE ([Extent2].[Score] <= 6) 
    )  AS [Distinct1]
)  AS [Project2]
)  AS [Project3]
```

Thanks beforehand!

Comment: can you please copy-paste the generated SQL?

Comment: @Jordi just updated with generated SQL

Comment: You're grouping, in which you're doing sums of counts. So it's not an easy query to do to begin with. Have you tried to analyze the query in a tool? See what is it actually doing when it's being executed? Beacuse the server will do all kinds of optimizations.

Comment: "It returns me what I need" it doesn't, it is not semantically identical to your original query.

Comment: @usr Could you please let me know why not?

Comment: @petro.sidlovskyy it is doing an inner join, need to use a left join. Also the counting looks funky.

Comment: @usr oh thanks. yes linq does inner join. However inner join is ok as well. Just need to simplify everything else. Counting may look ugly but it returns the same data. The question is how to make it simplier :)

Comment: @petro.sidlovskyy I think you'll get a wrong count. Try it with one A that has 3 B's. The SQL query will return 3, the LINQ query will return 9 (quadratic).

Answer (score 0):

When i change your ef clouse with

```
from a in db.A.DefaultIfEmpty()
        join b in db.B 
        on a.ID equals b.A_ID
        where b.Score <= 6
        group a by a.UserId into grouping
        select new 
        {
            UserId = (string) grouping.Key,                       
            RawValue = grouping.Count()
        };
```

my generated SQL change with

```
SELECT 
        1 AS [C1], 
        [GroupBy1].[K1] AS [UserId], 
        [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C2]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [Extent1].[UserId] AS [K1], 
            COUNT(1) AS [A1]
            FROM    ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[A] AS [Extent1] ON 1 = 1
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[B] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ID] = [Extent2].[A_ID]
            WHERE [Extent2].[Score] <= 6
            GROUP BY [Extent1].[UserId]
        )  AS [GroupBy1]
```

I think this is very good optimized result.